# Pauli decomposed Hamiltonian as Diagonal U gate

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, hamiltonian-simulation, pauli-gates

While trying to implement a quantum circuit, I had to apply Hadamard gates to all qubits to achieve equal superposition. Done.

The next operation is decomposing the Hamiltonian into a sum of tensor products of Pauli matrices. and then applying it as a diagonal U gate?

I have derived the terms of the Pauli decomposition of the in the form (co-efficient, $\\{X,Y,Z,I\\}^1$, $\\{X,Y,Z,I\\}^1$) using `pennylane.pauli_decompose(Hamiltonian_matrix)`

How can I implement the diagonal U gate (preferably in Qiskit)?

Also, what is the equivalent function of `pauli_decompose()` in Qiskit?

Comment: Maybe I got something wrong but I'm not sure about what you mean by "applying it as a diagonal U gate"; do you mean that you want to find some diagonal $U = B^{\dagger} \hat{H} B$ given your Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ and the proper change of basis represented by $B$?

Comment: Apart from the comment above, the Qiskit function to decompose a matrix to Pauli terms is [`SparsePauliOp.from_operator(Hamiltonian_matrix)`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp.from_operator.html) importing the `SparsePauliOp` class from the `qiskit.quantum_info` module.